# What is the inclusion order for `goog.require`?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I have searched everywhere and it seems i can't find an answer for this question: What is the order in which the google closure compiler resolves the dependencies using the `goog.require` function.

Example:

```
goog.require('work.Utils');
goog.require('work.Languages');
goog.require('work.BrowserData');
goog.require('work.EventSystem');
goog.require('work.FileDescriptor');
goog.require('work.Environment');
```

These are all required in a single file in the exact order as they would use one another. For example `work.BrowserData` uses `work.Languages`, but all of the files use `work.Utils`. So instead of requiring in each file the `work.Utils` I included on top so the compiler would load it first and then load the rest.

The problem is that after compilation the inclusion order is different:

```
work.EventSystem
work.FileDescriptor
work.Environment
work.BrowserData
work.Languages
work.Utils
```

That means at execution point neither of the files have access to `work.Utils` and `work.BrowserData` has issues of finding `work.Utils`.

Besides including every required file in every file( which is a tedious work to do for a large library), what is ( if it exists ) the other solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if other files require work.Utils then it should be required in those files.

Comment: my question was if there would be an easier solution because i would have to include almost everything everywhere and my app is really big. That was only an example.

Comment: You include things you use in a file (this excludes type declarations) else dependency management won't work as expected.

Comment: So if i try to create a type of inclusion order where if i include only my first file and inside it in order i require what i need it won't work in the exact order as i intend to ( C/C++ like ) ?